# Filtering an array of numbers according to a numeric pattern

Tags: php, arrays, repeat

There is an array of numbers:

```
$list = array
(
    [0] => 111
    [1] => 112
    [2] => 113
    [3] => 114
    [4] => 121
    [5] => 122
    [6] => 123
    [7] => 124
    [8] => 131
    [9] => 132
    [10] => 1234
    [11] => 1123
    [12] => 1223
    [13] => 1233
    [14] => 4321
)
```

and a variable (the pattern):

```
$input = 1231;
```

I would like to filter the array with the following rules. Let `$list[$i]` be an item of the `$list` array, `$d` be a digit of `$list[$i]`. Then

- if the count of digits equal to `$d` in `$list[$i]` is greater than the count of digits equal to `$d` in `$input`, then the array item must be skipped;
- if there is no `$d` digit specified in `$input`, then the array item must be skipped.

For example, in the above-mentioned `$input` variable

- `1` appears twice,
- `2` and `3` appear once.

Then everything that appears more than this should be removed from the array:

```
$list = array
(
    [0] => 111  ==> should be removed (1 is only defined twice in $input, so it shouldn't appear more than twice)
    [1] => 112  
    [2] => 113 
    [3] => 114  ==> should be removed (there is no 4)
    [4] => 121  
    [5] => 122  ==> should be removed (2 is only defined once, so it shouldn't appear more than once)
    [6] => 123
    [7] => 124  ==> should be removed (there is no 4)
    [8] => 131
    [9] => 132
    [10] => 1234  ==> should be removed (there is no 4)
    [11] => 1123  
    [12] => 1223  ==> should be removed (2 is only defined once in $input, so it shouldn't appear more than once)
    [13] => 1233  ==> should be removed (3 is only defined once in $input, so it shouldn't appear more than once)
    [14] => 4321  ==> should be removed (there is no 4)
)
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: why 111,112.. should be removed?

Comment: you could try something with [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) and [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: Why in the world `111` should be removed and `123` stays? What is the logic behind this. You need to tell us the reason not just the result you want.

Comment: @MuhammedImranHussain And Irvin Because it's a duplicate i think. 111 is a triple. 112 is a double. It contains the number 1 multiple times :)

Comment: I think it's duplicate digits within the number

Comment: @MuhammedImranHussain because number-1 is only defined as once in $input, so it shouldn't appear more than once

Comment: Okay. Got it. The item in which numbers appear more than once.

Comment: @mitch yes. unless the $input is 1123 ==> the number 1 can appears twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Prepare counters for the digits in $input
foreach (str_split((string)$input) as $d)
  @$counters[$d]++;

$result = [];

foreach ($list as $key => $n) {
  // Counter for digits in $n
  $tmp_counter = [];

  foreach (str_split((string)$n) as $d) {
    // $d is not specified in $input, so skip $n
    if (empty($counters[$d]))
      continue 2;

    // The number of $d entries in $n is greater than
    // it is specified in $input, so skip $n
    if (@++$tmp_counter[$d] > $counters[$d])
      continue 2;
  }

  $result[$key] = $n;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please let me know if it works

```
$input = 1123;
$output = array(111,112,113,114,121,122,123,124,131,132, 1234, 1123, 1223, 1233, 4321);
$count = count_chars($input, 1);
$result = array_filter($output, function($n) use($input, $count) {
   foreach(count_chars($n, 1) as $i => $val) {
        if(strpos($input, $i) === false) {
            return 0;
        }else if($val > $count[$i]){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
});
```

Comment: Warning Error Message: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string

Comment: where you $input declared

Comment: Got this now : Warning Error Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: I used my variable, can you please paste your code?

Comment: @oitoit I think you have updated your requirement that based on input letter count element can contain that much of repetition. For example if input contain 11 then in array 1 twice acceptable. I will update my code. at first confirm code works without error

Comment: $input = 1123;
$output = array(111,112,113,114,121,122,123,124,131,132, 1234, 1123, 1223, 1233, 4321);
The output is only : 123 and 132 which is still incorrect

Comment: someone posted the answer and works well! Thanks a lot for your help anyway :)

Answer (score -1):

```
    For that you can check count of array by splinting and array_unique methode of PHP.


    $main_arr = array(111,112,113,114,121,122,123,124,131,132,1234,1123,1223,1233,4321);

    $ans = [];
    foreach ($main_arr as $value){
        $sub_arr = str_split($value);
        if(count($sub_arr) == count(array_unique($sub_arr))){
            array_push($ans,$value);
        }
    }
    print_r($ans);

This will output:

Array ( 
[0] => 123
[1] => 124 
[2] => 132 
[3] => 1234 
[4] => 4321
)

Thanks
```

Comment: The OP wants to remove the duplicate numbers that are given in the `$input` variable, not all entries that have duplicate numbers.